# Android when use PreferenceCategory and when PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I am learning about android but i do not understand the difference between PreferenceCategory and PreferenceScreen, i saw that many tutorial used the second one instead the first one, but i do not understand why.
When you recommend me to use the first one instead the second or vice versa.
Another thing, does these two codes made the same thing?

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="first">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="first_preferences"
        android:title="first"
        android:defaultValue="false" />`
</PreferenceCategory>
```

and the second code:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="second">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="second_preferences"
        android:title="second"
        android:defaultValue="false" />`
</PreferenceScreen>
```

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

`PreferenceScreen` is a container of preferences.

Inside the `PreferenceScreen`, you can **categorize** the content by `PreferenceCategory`. Below example will show you the difference between `PreferenceScreen` and `PreferenceCategory`.

Example:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="USER PROFILE" >
        <EditTextPreference 
                android:title="Set username" 
                android:summary="Set your username" 
                android:key="prefUsername"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="UPDATE SETTINGS" >
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="prefSendReport"
            android:summary="Helps to fix bugs"
            android:title="Send crash reports" >
        </CheckBoxPreference>

        <ListPreference
            android:key="prefSyncFrequency"
            android:entries="@array/syncFrequency"
            android:summary="@string/pref_sync_frequency_summary" 
            android:entryValues="Helps to fix bugs"
            android:title="Sync frequency" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

The above XML will produce the below output.

[image]

Now you can see the PrefereceCategory is **categorizing** the content.

Answer (score 1):

A preference `Screen` is the root layout which contains the settings.
A preference `Category` is a "title" for a group of related settings.